# MYSQL select last two blocks of entries based on entry days

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has multiple entries in a day. I'd like the last two sets of entries.

value | timeIn |  id

[image]

```
select * from db.table t
where t.r_id = 76703
order by timeIn DESC
LIMIT 2
```

I want to add a group by timeIn (the time column) but show the individual rows inside. By limit 2, I mean I want two groups.  (Basically out of a table, get the last two (earliest dates to today) groups of values for the id on the right

Comment: Can you provide the resultset you want to get out of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the specified result set.

As I understand what you are asking, to restate the specification in different words: you want to find the second highest (distinct) `timeIn` value from the table (for a given value of `r_id`), and then you want to return all rows from the table (for the given value of `r_id`) that have a `timeIn` value that is greater than or equal to the second highest `timeIn` value. By "set", you mean the collection of rows that have a matching `r_id` and `timeIn` value.  (It's entirely possible I've misunderstood the specification.)

Here's one way to get the specified rows:

```
SELECT d.value
     , d.timeIn
     , d.r_id
  FROM mytable d
 WHERE d.r_id = 76703
   AND d.timeIn >=
       ( SELECT MAX(m2.timeIn) AS m2_timeIn
           FROM mytable m2
          WHERE m2.r_id = 76703
            AND m2.timeIn < 
                ( SELECT MAX(m1.timeIn) AS m1_timeIn
                    FROM mytable m1
                   WHERE m1.r_id = 76703
                )
       )
 ORDER BY d.timeIn DESC, d.value ASC
```

---

**NOTE**

Performance of this query is going to depend on an index with a leading columns of **`r_id`** and **`timeIn`**, because of the equality predicate, and the range scan.

```
... ON mytable (r_id, timeIn, ... )
```

An `EXPLAIN` will show the steps in the plan. MySQL should run that innermost query first, to get the first highest `timeIn` value. Then MySQL should run the query against m2, to get the second highest `timeIn` value. With that as a constant, MySQL should run the query against `d` to get ...

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Also, it's important that the predicate with the literal `76703` be in the outer query, and the subqueries. (There's temptation there to make those into correlated subqueries, to replace the literals with references from the higher query... but for performance sake, you don't want to do that (because of the way MySQL processes correlated subqueries.) You won't notice a problem on small sets, but with larger sets, the performance penalty becomes noticeable, and with huge sets, the performance becomes unbearable.

For getting only the two highest to values, the  `MAX(foo) WHERE foo < (SELECT MAX(foo)` approach is probably the most efficient. Obviously, this could be extended to three, four, etc.

But to get the hundred highest values, the SQL becomes unwieldy.

Another approach to getting the **`n`**-th highest value would be to use a query something like this:

```
SELECT mn.timeIn
  FROM mytable mn
 WHERE mn.r_id = 76703
 GROUP BY mn.timeIn
 LIMIT n-1 ,1
```

where **`n-1`** represents the number of "highest" values you want to skip. (For example, to get the 10th highest value, you'd specify `LIMIT 9,1`.)

Note that if there aren't at least "n" distinct values for timeIn, this query won't return a row (the same is true for the approach used in the first query.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
 Select * from db.table t
 where t.r_id = 76703
 AND timeIn >= (select distinct timeIn from db.table t
                WHERE r_id = 76703  
                ORDER BY timeIN desc LIMIT 1, 1)
```

The subquery selects the second item in descending order from unique timeIns, and the outer query selects all records where the timeIn is greater or equal to that record.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to return the specified resultset. The **`r_id = 76703`** predicate needs to be repeated in the subquery.

Comment: To get the second highest value, you'd want **`LIMIT 1,1`** in place of `LIMIT 2,1`. That first integer specifies the number of rows to "skip". (To get the first row, it would be `LIMIT 0,1`.

Comment: The query in this answer now returns the specified result set. (I recommend qualifying *all* column references in both the outer query and the subquery, and recommend using a different table alias in the subquery; that makes it easier for the reader to recognize which table a column reference refers to, and makes it easier to correlate to the output from an `EXPLAIN`. I'd also recommend specifying the columns to be returned, rather than using `*`.)

Comment: I built it quick and dirty to get the OP on the right track

Answer (score -1):

this may work...

```
   select * from db.table t
   where timeIn<=select timeIn from db.table order by  timeIn DESC limit 1 
        or
        time>=(select timeIn from db.table 
              where time<(select timeIn from db.table order by  timeIn DESC limit 1) 
              order by  timeIn DESC limit 1
```

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to return the specified resultset. The **`r_id = 76703`** predicate is missing from the query; it's not clear why an **`OR`** would be required; and certainly can't follow an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause in a query; this isn't valid syntax.